# Recursive File Move

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a large collection of files that I'm trying to organize. All files are zip archives. I have a main directory with a bunch of sub-directories. All files are located within the sub-directories. The file structure is as follows

```
games/gs1/games.zip    
games/gs2/games.zip    
games/gs3/games.zip
```

What I'd like to do is run a shell script that will go to each sub-directory, create a folder titled USA, find all files in that sub-directory with (USA) in the filename, and move them to the new folder. I should have a file structure like

```
games/gs1/USA/gs1-1(USA).zip
games/gs1/USA/gs1-2(USA).zip

games/gs2/USA/gs2-1(USA).zip
games/gs2/USA/gs2-2(USA).zip
```

I tried

```
for d in ./*/
do
    cd $d
    mkdir -p USA
    find . -name '*(USA)*' -exec echo mv -t ./USA {} +
done
```

But it just showed all the files being moved to games/USA.

Comment: If you want to perform the move, remove `echo`.

Comment: How many zip files do you have?

Comment: After the first loop you need to return to the start directory. You could chacge `cd $d` into `cd $d || continue` and add a line `cd -`. An easier/safer construction is using `()`: `for d in ./*/; do (cd $d; pwd); done`

Comment: Use `pushd` instead of `cd to change the working directory, then use `popd` after `find` to return to the directory where `./*` was evaluated in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do it without `find` with just globs alone:

```
#! /bin/bash

for dname in ./*/; do
    mkdir "$dname/USA"
    mv "$dname"/*USA*.zip "$dname/USA"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

**bash** + **find** solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read f; do
    old_path="${f%/*}"
    fn="${f##*/}"
    new_path="$old_path/USA"
    mkdir "$new_path"
    mv "$f" "$new_path/$fn"
done < <(find /maindir -type f -name "*(USA)*.zip")
```